# No such table Django Database

Tags: sql, django, database, sqlite, django-models

So I created a model for storing credentials from Gmail users.
I wanted to make migrations but it says that there is no such table:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: mainApp_credentialsmodel
```

My models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
import json


class CredentialsModel(models.Model):
  id = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  credential = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Calling that model for checking authorization:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

store = CredentialsModel.objects.all()
creds = store.get()


if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('mainApp/client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

Comment: can you post the last migrations files that you have inside this app `mainApp_credentialsmodel`?

Answer (score 0):

python manage.py makemigrations
If that error keep happening, check your migrations folder and check the files inside. Also check If your database is online, in case you have a database online, I've got this problem last week, but it was a problem with azure.
In last case I would create the table (model) again, changing the name to something similar, but If you have a significant amount of data in that table, then I think you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your authorization code - including the query on CredentialsModel - is at module level. This means it runs when the module is imported, which happens before the migration has had a chance to run.

You must ensure that any database-accessing code is inside a function or method and is not invoked globally.

Comment: I deleted everything in migrations directory and deleted my .slite3 database file, also removed all imported models from "quickstart.py" and ran "makemigrations","migrate". Everything went well. After this I imported CredentialsModel into "quickstart.py" and tried to migrate again but it shows up: mainApp.models.DoesNotExist: CredentialsModel matching query does not exist.